# CSS + JQUERY + event.preventdefault

Tags: jquery, css, events

In this table, the row has a event in jquery and execute it when i click in the row, inside of the row there are a div... these div has too a event and this execute when i click in the div. but when i click in the div too execute the event of the row....

```
<table>
 <tr id="one">
  <td>
   <div id="two">
    Hellow world
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So, when i click in the div, i want execute only the event of the div. how?

Comment: `preventDefault` stops the default action from occurring. `stopPropagation` stops bubbling. `stopImmediatePropagation` will stop any other event handlers from firing that are assigned to the same element.

Comment: i edit my post with the events for the div and the row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery, and make sure you pass "event" as parameter to the function

```
 $(document).on('click', '.desplegar' , function(event) {
  .................
  event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

this will prevent bubbling up of events.

Comment: It does not work yet. I was checking in firebug firefox and get this error:
"ReferenceError: event is not defined
event.stopPropagation();"
And after that I guess it works for me because it stops on error and not because event.stopPropagation(); 
However nothing happens in chorme

Comment: are you sure you passing "event" as an parameter, if not you will get not defined error.

Comment: sorry, I did not see the event as a parameter in your edition. that work good. tnx

Answer (score 5):

```
ev.stopPropagation()
```

is what you are wondering about.

Comment: that work in firefox for me, but dont work in chrome

Comment: There is this wonderful site, jquery.com, it contains mystical documentation that answers all. I recommend spending 20 minutes of your time to skim the methods available. It will be enlightening and a super time saver rather than using this every time.